# ERROR :Text string must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: react-native

I am writing this code for a message screen

```js
<Screen>
  <FlatList
    data={Message}
    keyExtractor={(Message) => Message.id.toString}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <ListItem
        title={item.title}
        subtitle={item.description}
        image={item.image}
        onPress={() => console.log("message selected", item)}
      />
    )}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
  />
</Screen>;
```

And getting this error :

> ERROR  Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
>
> ```
> This error is located at:
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by Screen)
>     in Screen (created by MessagesScreen)
>     in MessagesScreen (created by App)
>     in App (created by withDevTools(App))
>     in withDevTools(App)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by AppContainer)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by AppContainer)
>     in AppContainer
>     in main(RootComponent)
> ```

Comment: Please post your code for ListItem for better reference. 
Generally any text even an empty '' needs to be added within the <Text> Component

Comment: function ListItem({title,subtitle,image,onPress}) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
        underlayColor={"#f8f4f4"}
        onPress ={onPress}>

    <View style ={styles.container}>
        <Image style = {styles.image} source ={image}/>
        <View>
            <Apptext style={styles.title}>{title}</Apptext>
            <Apptext style={styles.subtitle}>{subtitle}</Apptext>
        </View>

    </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}

Comment: Where do you import `Apptext`?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that is text undefined. Like that;

```
<ListItem  
    title={item.title ? item.title : ""}
 subtitle={item.description ? item.description : ""} 
image={item.image} 
 onPress={()=>console.log("message selected", item)}/>
```